# WSO2 AS 5.2.1. Servlet Exception while making the decision : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: wso2

i was actual trying this tutorial: http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2012/12/providing-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-webapps/

on the authentication with admin:admin on localhost:9763/Entitlement_Sample_WebApp/protected.jsp i encountered an error:

---

exception

org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.filter.exception.EntitlementFilterException: Exception while making the decision : java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.filter.EntitlementFilter.doFilter(EntitlementFilter.java:191)

---

My WSO2 IS PDP receives the request and responds also correctly with a XACML Response : Permit
so where could be the problem ??

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem caused by an error of `EntitlementFilter`, so I could solve this by correcting the source file `EntitlementFilter.java` (line 191)
like below:

```
simpleDecision = decisionElement.getFirstChildWithName(new QName("Result")).getFirstChildWithName(new QName("Decision")).getText();
```

rewrite it:

```
simpleDecision = decisionElement.getFirstChildWithName(new QName(“urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17″,”Result”)).
getFirstChildWithName(new QName(“urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17″,”Decision”)).getText();
```

It ommitted namespace in QName method

The detail is here (https://nparkstar.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/wso2-as-sample-authorization-%EC%98%A4%EB%A5%98-%EC%88%98%EC%A0%95/).
Sorry, it is written in Korean, but I wish it could helpful.

Comment: Hi, how to crrect this file "EntitlementFilter.java" ; i have the same problem. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It could be anywhere starting from this line :  pepProxy.getDecision(userName, resource, action, env)

It could be in your pepProxy code, where they are getting back the result, or might be in the other lines after this call in that try catch.

One thing is sure PDP is not at all culprit.

Please paste your full exception here if you want to know precise problem  + Solution.

:)